# how to run gulp minify on pre-commit?

Tags: git, gulp, pre-commit-hook, package.json, pre-commit

I have a gulp task that runs a minification of several files, and it works perfectly when I run the command `gulp minify` from the command line. What I'm trying to do is to run this command automatically on pre-commit, but the minified files are not generated. I've installed [pre-commit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/precommit-hook) hook of npm, and I'm basically doing something similar to what's presented in this article:

http://x-team.com/2014/11/fearless-development-cycle-git-hooks/

This is part of my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.3",
  "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
  "precommit-hook": "^3.0.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js",
  "minify": "gulp minify"
},

"pre-commit": [
  "minify"
]
```

I've tried both "pre-commit" and "precommit" in my package.json, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It does not go in your package.json. You need to add a file called `pre-commit` under `.git/hooks` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
gulp minify
```

Also make sure the `pre-commit` file is executable. Run this:
`chmod +x pre-commit`